# Haskell working on char list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am new to Haskell and I have a polygon represented as a list of vertices

```
vert = ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']
```

and I want to return all the diagonals. The result should be

```
[(m, o), (m, p), (n, p), (n, q), (o, q)]
```

I have the below code but I got an error `parse error on input if` and even though I would put only `(tail (find2 x vert))` I got a lot of other errors.

```
vert = ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']
find2 :: Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
find2 ch (x:xs) = if x == ch then (x:xs) else find2 ch xs

diagonals = foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ 
                                foldl (\ acc2 y -> acc2 ++ (x:y) 
                                [] 
                                if x == (head vert) 
                                    then (init (tail (find2 x vert)))
                                    else (tail (find2 x vert)))
        [] vert
```

The find2 function returns the sublist of a list starting from a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your original code, as listed in the bottom.

I tried to fix the **grammar** and got something that compiles, not sure if the behavior is correct or what you need:

```
vert = ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']
find2 :: Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
find2 ch (x:xs) = if x == ch then (x:xs) else find2 ch xs

diagonals = foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ 
                              foldl (\ acc2 y -> acc2 ++ [x] ++ [y]) [] 
                                (if x == (head vert) 
                                    then (init (tail (find2 x vert)))
                                    else (tail (find2 x vert))) )
        [] vert
```

The output:

```
*Main> diagonals
"mnmompnonpnqopoqpq"
```

Not sure if the logic is correct, and maybe you need to inspect it further.

The issues with the original code are:

First, I think there is a missing `)` in the line `foldl (\ acc2 y -> acc2 ++ (x:y)`.

Second, I think you need to put the `if` expression in a parenthesis.

Third, the type of your `foldl` (e.g. the 2nd one) and the type of `tail (find2 x vert)))` do not match. You need to modify the definition of the `foldl` to at least make sure the type is correct.

Forth, the variable `vertiges` is undefined.

-- Edit --

To obtain the actual diagonals, a quick and dirty way (not necessarily most efficient) is to use list comprehension to construct edges and filter out those whose vertices are neighbors to each other, i.e. those with vertex distance (`dist`) being 1 or n-1. A sample code is as follows:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

dist a b vert = abs( fromJust(elemIndex a vert) - fromJust(elemIndex b vert)) `mod` length vert

diagonals' = [(a,b) | a <- vert, b <- vert, a < b, 
     dist a b vert /= 1, dist a b vert /= length vert -1]
```

Output:

```
*Main> diagonals'
[('m','o'),('m','p'),('n','p'),('n','q'),('o','q')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define diagonals as the difference between all edges and sides, which both will be easier to generate

for example

```
edges :: [a] -> [(a,a)]                                
edges [] = []                      
edges [x] = []
edges (x:xs) = (map ((,) x) xs) ++ edges xs
```

and

```
sides :: [a] -> [(a,a)] 
sides [] = []
sides [x] = []
sides (x:xs) = zip (x:x:init xs) (last xs:xs)
```

now

```
import Data.List((\\))
diagonals x = edges x \\ sides x
```

a triangle shouldn't have any diagonals

```
> diagonals [1..3]
[]

> diagonals [1..4]
[(1,3),(2,4)]

> diagonals vert
[('m','o'),('m','p'),('n','p'),('n','q'),('o','q')]
```